# Scrolling area cut off when using padding-top

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a bootstrap template that has a fixed header, the content is set off using `padding-top` in order not to be hidden by that header, see [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/21yMvlGhGaHn5ENRkrml?p=preview) to get an idea.

The body has `overflow` set to `hidden` so that all the other parts of the UI (sidebar, context menu etc.) are confined to the current browser viewport.

The trouble starts if I enable `overflow-y` for the content, I tried to set `height` to `100vh` and although that brings the scrollbar back, the content is cut off at the bottom, which is totally plausible but I have no idea what to do about it.

Is there a straightforward solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%; // <---
}
section {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;  // <---
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 14pt;
    box-sizing: border-box;  // <---
}
section div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%; // <---
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  // <---
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHSN56eT4y5KFBoBu5Zc?p=preview)

The idea is making `html`, `body`, `section` and `section div` `height: 100%` so that they are stretched exactly as high as your viewport.

`box-sizing: border-box` should be added to `section` and `section div` so as to include padding into the height of them.

With `overflow-y: auto;` on `section div`, the content is scrolled inside `section div`.

Comment: Awesome! I was about to do all kinds of workarounds, this answer does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `margin` to the CSS of your containing div.

Something along the lines of this:

```
section {
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px; // adjust accordingly
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately - http://plnkr.co/edit/21yMvlGhGaHn5ENRkrml?p=preview

Comment: @Aredhel hmm, this normally works for me! Apologies. I'll attempt to edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set height to around `92vh or 93vh` and see if that works

```
section div {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 93vh;
  padding: 10px;
}
```